# how to set the position of bitmap data in action script?

Tags: flash, actionscript

Am developing an application using action script.I want to display an image at the center of the satge programmatically..can anyone suggest how to set the possition to BitmapData?.my code is

```
   var mysprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
   var mybitmap_data:BitmapData = new atkbr_jpg(500,600) as BitmapData;
   var mybitmap:Bitmap;

   mybitmap=new Bitmap(mybitmap_data);
   mysprite.addChild(mybitmap);

   stage.addChild(mysprite);
```

Comment: use the bitmap size and stage size to calculate the center position: myBitmap.x = stage.width/2-mybitmap.width/2

Comment: i am not able to set the position.if i calculate and set the value to myBitmap.x i am getting an error like this TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.at rolsdial_fla::Symbol1_1/displayimage([rolsdial_fla.Symbol1_1::frame:6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can center your Bitmap like that:

```
var mybitmap_data:atkbr_jpg = new atkbr_jpg();
var mybitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(mybitmap_data);
var mysprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
mysprite.addChild(mybitmap);
mysprite.x = (stage.stageWidth - mysprite.width) / 2;
mysprite.y = (stage.stageHeight - mysprite.height) / 2;
addChild(mysprite);
```

Comment: how to access the keyframes programmatically in actionscript?

Comment: @rams It's another subject... you should ask this question on StackOverflow.